# Suitable package for spatio-temporal prediction with R

Tags: r, gis, spatial, prediction, temporal

I’m new to R and it’s use for spatio-temporal data. Over the last few weeks I’ve learned the basics of R and have tried to find a suitable package/suitable functions for creating a spatio-temporal prediction model.

I’ve found several packages for diverse spatio-temporal methods of analysis (such as SpatioTemporal, spTimer etc.), however, I find some of these functions/packages quite complex, digging through them often resulted in finding issues that might prove them unsuitable for my data or the aim of my research. So I’m having difficulty determining with certainty which package(s) and functions are suitable for my data and the aim of my research. Searching through topics on SO it seems that there are quite a few experts on (spatio-temporal) analyses with R. So I’m hoping that one of you could provide me with some certainty on package(s) and functions that are suitable for my research.

Research:
The aim of my research is to create a spatio-temporal prediction model that can predict the probability of the occurrence of violent crime within a city, based on geotagged twitter messages.

Data:
There are two main components of my data: Incidents and tweets

Incidents: 
I have two seperate datasets of incident data within the city (of two separate time periods) , these include violent crime incidents within the city (with each row as a separate case/incident). The relevant columns include: `Datetime` (Y%-m%-d% H%:M%, as POSIXct(for now)), `Latitude` and `Longitude` coordinates (separate variables). So these include the date and time of an incident and the lat/long coordinates of the point location of an incident.

Tweets:
This dataset includes tweets (covering the aforementioned time periods) sent from within the city, which were aggregated using keywords indicating certain activities/mood states.
Like the incident data this set includes: `Datetime` (same format as above), `Latitude` and `Longitude` coordinates. And (among others) additionally the variable `Keywordcluster` which indicates the cluster which contains the relevant keywords found in the tweets (with 21 clusters containing keywords related to different types of activities or mood states).

So both the incidents as well as the tweets contain columns indicating the exact time and exact point locations (as latitude and longitude coordinates). The aim is to use the different keyword clusters that are prevalent in the separate tweets (for example: one cluster contains keywords related to alcohol use)  to predict the probabilities of the occurrence of violent crime incidents within areas.

As the goal is to predict violent crime based on twitter messages, it would be preferable that the model only takes into account tweets sent (within a short time period) before the occurrence of an incident (for instance: the tweets sent up to 24 hours before an incident). The aim is to provide the probabilities of the occurrence of violent crime within certain areas between certain short timespans (such as hours, or days at maximum, because of the nature of the data (i.e. not using tweets to predict the occurrence of an incident a week later)).

I hope this provides an adequate explanation of my data and the aim of my research. I would be extremely grateful if one of you could provide some certainty concerning which package(s) and functions should be suitable (and perhaps some additional tips). This would really help me out a lot!

Thanks in advance,
M. Stam

Comment: This link has many packages indexed by category. Maybe it can help. [Cran: Spatio Temporal Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/SpatioTemporal.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. That does give a nice overview of all of the packages. However, I am looking for someone who can confirm which packages/functions are suitable for my data/research. But thanks for the reply!

Comment: Did you find anything so far? I am also very interested in these topics (1. spatio-temporal data, 2. prediction of incidences based on message) Would be very grateful if you could give an update on what you found, which package did not work for you (what reasons and what you miss in current implementations)... I am planning on writing some R methods on my own and in case the intereset is big enough I might create a package..

Comment: Hey Verena, Unfortunately thusfar I am still facing the issue as described in my post. As you've probably noticed there is a myriad of packages and functions concerning spatiotemporal analyses and as of yet i still haven't been able to determine with certainty which one (if any) is suitable for my data and research goal. I am trying to contact an expert in this specific field. So I will keep you posted if/when I'll make any progress.